# Handling variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, variables, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that needs to handle up to 60 different variables.

The variables have a standardized naming convention.

```
@TextParameter1 varchar(443) = NULL, 
@TextParameter2 varchar(443) = NULL,
@TextParameter3 varchar(443) = NULL
```

I need to be able to check which variables are `NULL` and which aren't, and then handle the values of the non-null variables.

I tried using dynamic SQL to iterate over the variables by making the first portion of the variable name a string and iterating through the numbers on the end.

```
declare @rownum int = 1

while @rownum <= 60
    declare @var_sql nvarchar(max) = 'INSERT INTO #slicer 
                                          SELECT IDENTITY(Int, 1, 1) AS rowkey, value  
                                          FROM STRING_SPLIT(CAST(@DetailQueryTextParameter' + CAST(@rownum AS nvarchar(3)) AS varchar(4000)), '^')'

execute @var_sql
Set @rownum = @rownum + 1
```

This will return an error claiming that `@DetailQueryTextParameter` needs to be declared first. What is the best way to handle all of these variables? I could do by writing a line of code for every single variable, but it seems like there is a better way. Can I insert the variable names into a table and iterate from there?

Comment: This cannot be done; variables in an outer scope are not visible to an inner dynamic scope. The only way to do this is to write out the statement in its entirety, or generate the procedure body in its entirety. The real question, of course, is why you're using 60 variables, instead of something more manageable, like a table-valued parameter.

Comment: Most certainly sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) here. You *can* pass the parameters to a dynamic statement, if you (again) parametrise them when calling `sys.sp_executesql` but I completely agree that you likely *don't* need 60 variables, and more likely want a TVP.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? If you have 60 variables or parameters you need a table, not individual values. SQL is a set-based language and loops are almost never a good idea. The question's code seems to be trying to save the variables in a table, so why not do that directly?

Comment: Also: if you want to have *multiple statements* for a `while` loop - you **must use** a `begin ... end` construct; right now, *only* the `declare` is part of the `while` - everything else would be *after* the `while` loop (because you're lacking the `begin ... end`)

Comment: I have been asked to create a procedure that can handle up to 60 variables because each variable can represent a different slicer. So '@'TextParam1 could be office_ids, '@'TextParam2 could be addresses and so on.  The values of each non-null variable gets plugged into a dynamic sql script as a different possible slicer.  Is there a way I can plug each variable value into a table, without having to write 'if '@'Text Parameter is <> null --do this' 60 times? This procedure call will come from our SSRS team. Yes Im aware I left the BEGIN/END statements off. They are in the code

Comment: Rather than variables (perhaps you really mean parameters), consider passing the "slicers" as json and use the actual names instead of generic names (e.g. `{"office_ids":[1,2,3], "addresses":["addr1","addr2"]}`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have a statement that does something similar   set @DetailQuery=(select replace(@DetailQuery, '@DetailQueryDateParameter1',@DetailQueryDateParameter1))   but I still need to check to see what parameters are being called upon. Most of the time only a few parameters will be used, other times  all 63 could be used. I'll look into using Json, but im not sure if that will be an option.

Answer (score 2):

(The below was updated to include the `SPLIT_STRING()`.)

You can use a `VALUES` subselect (not sure if that is the proper term) to combine all of your parameters into a single collection. You can then filter out the null values and pass the remaining values into `STRING_SPLIT()` using a `CROSS APPLY`.

```
DECLARE
    @TextParameter1 varchar(443) = NULL, 
    @TextParameter2 varchar(443) = 'aaa^bbb',
    @TextParameter3 varchar(443) = NULL,
    @TextParameter4 varchar(443) = 'xxx^yyy^zzz',
    @TextParameter5 varchar(443) = NULL
    
SELECT A.*, B.Value AS SplitValue
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, @TextParameter1),
        (2, @TextParameter2),
        (3, @TextParameter3),
        (4, @TextParameter4),
        (5, @TextParameter5)
) A(Parameter, Value)
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(A.Value, '^') B
WHERE A.Value IS NOT NULL
```

Which would yield results like:

| Parameter | Value | SplitValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | aaa^bbb | aaa |
| 2 | aaa^bbb | bbb |
| 4 | xxx^yyy^zzz | xxx |
| 4 | xxx^yyy^zzz | yyy |
| 4 | xxx^yyy^zzz | zzz |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B-GtIz8z).

Comment: This is what I was working on but with a table variable.

Comment: I'm not the OP, you gave the same answer I was working on. So upvote for you.